# Using a value with trailing spaces in a variable, keeping the spaces

Tags: command-line, bash, udev

I can normally answer my questions on t'internet but my googlefu and understanding have let me down this time.

I have a bash script I'm putting together that I'm using to populate a UDEV rule. To do this I use a grep of udevadm info, like this:

```bsh
install_user=jlivin25
drive_number=sr1
env_ammend=CD
drive_model=$(udevadm info -a -n /dev/sr1 | grep ATTRS{model}==)

udev_insert=$(echo -e "ACTION==\"change\",KERNEL==\""$drive_number"\",SUBSYSTEM==\"block\","\"$drive_model"\",ENV{ID_CDROM_MEDIA_"$env_ammend"}==\"1\",ENV{HOME}=\"/home/"$install_user"\",RUN+=\"/bin/systemctl start "${env_ammend}_ripping.service"\"")
```

This works really well, however, the stumbling block I've come across is that the result of `udevadm info -a -n /dev/sr1 | grep ATTRS{model}==` gives `ATTRS{model}=="BD-CMB UJ160    "`.

You can see here that the result from the grep includes trailing spaces. As soon as I store the result in a variable and try to use it I lose the spaces.

Reading on the internet explains that `""` are used to stop the     being lost, like this:

`echo $drive_model`

gives

`ATTRS{model}=="BD-CMB UJ160 "`

`echo "$drive_model"`

gives

`ATTRS{model}=="BD-CMB UJ160    "`

but I can't seem to get that to work when populating the UDEV. The result I get is:

```bsh
ACTION=="change",KERNEL=="sr1",SUBSYSTEM=="block"," ATTRS{model}=="BD-CMB UJ160 "",ENV{ID_CDROM_MEDIA_CD}=="1",ENV{HOME}="/home/jlivin25",RUN+="/bin/systemctl start CD_ripping.service"
```

but what I want is:

```bsh
ACTION=="change",KERNEL=="sr1",SUBSYSTEM=="block"," ATTRS{model}=="BD-CMB UJ160 
   ",ENV{ID_CDROM_MEDIA_CD}=="1",ENV{HOME}="/home/jlivin25",RUN+="/bin/systemctl start CD_ripping.service"
```

Can anyone help me with this one, I'd really love an explanation of any solution so I can learn

Comment: but I think you should use `TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="${env_ammend}_ripping.service"` instead of `RUN+=`

Comment: you could do grep more specific `| grep -o 'ATTRS{model}=="[^"]*"'`

Comment: @bac0n thanks for the comments, can you explain more why you think this is a better approach, happy to take on board.

Comment: `-o` only return the matching part, it will trim eventual leading or trailing spaces. `"[^"]*"` matches everything in between. `RUN+=` runs your script in a sandbox and everything gets thrown away when the sandbox gets discarded, but TAG+= passes/mark your rule for systemd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike some other languages, `bash` reads quotes from left to right, literally. The first quotation mark sets the basis for the subsequent characters, which will abide by its rules until a matching quotation mark terminates the quote. In that sense, you could say that `bash` does not  *nest* quotes.

example:

```
'ACTION=="change",KERNEL=="'  "$drive_number"  '",SUBSYSTEM=="block",' ...
^ string one---------------^  ^ string two--^  ^ string three--------^
```

The complete line will look something like this:

```
udev_insert='ACTION=="change",KERNEL=="'"$drive_number"'",SUBSYSTEM=="block",'"$drive_model"',ENV{ID_CDROM_MEDIA_'"$env_ammend"'}=="1",ENV{HOME}="/home/'"$install_user"'",RUN+="/bin/systemctl start '"${env_ammend}_ripping.service"\"
```

You could also use `+=` operator to append to a variable:

```
udev_insert='ACTION=="change",KERNEL=="'
udev_insert+="$drive_number"
udev_insert+='",SUBSYSTEM=="block",'
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, cracking work! I'll take look later as to how this manifests. 

Comment: many thanks for this, worked perfectly once I got the order of things right, for anyone else that pops along, this worked. ```drive_model=$(udevadm info -a -n /dev/sr1 | grep -o 'ATTRS{model}=="[^"]*"')```. Then;
  ```udev_insert='ACTION=="change",KERNEL=="'"$drive_number"'",SUBSYSTEM=="block",'"$drive_model"',ENV{ID_CDROM_MEDIA_'"$env_ammend"'}=="1",ENV{HOME}="/home/'"$install_user"'",RUN+="/bin/systemctl start '"${env_ammend}"'_ripping.service"'``` for the rule.
```echo "$udev_insert" > $udev_rule```

Comment: nice, still think you should go for `TAG+=, ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}`, the `RUN+=` isn't intended run in this way, if you read `man udev` last paragraph for *RUN*

Comment: Secondly, just a thought, if you dynamically fetch the model from */dev/sr1*, that should basically be the same as `ATTRS{model}=="*"` this will render the tag unnecessary. If you, of course, intend to make sure it has a model property, to begin with, in that case, you should use `ATTRS{model}=="?*"`).

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, `printf` is a good choice here to help with the quoting:

```bsh
user_home=$(getent passwd "$install_user" | cut -d: -f 6)
fmt='ACTION=="change",KERNEL=="%s",SUBSYSTEM=="block","%s",ENV{ID_CDROM_MEDIA_%s}=="1",ENV{HOME}="%s",RUN+="/bin/systemctl start "%s_ripping.service"'
printf -v udev_insert "$fmt" "$drive_number" "$drive_model" "$env_ammend" "$user_home" $env_ammend"
```

Comment: *$drive_model* contains the complete expression,  plain %s will do. I always forget printf, a bit cleaner solution